# Second axios post request does not send

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to make two calls with axios post. The first call works as expected, the second call does not send.

I am calling the following function. The first call logs the url, body and response body. The second call only logs the url and body. It doesn't drop into the `.then` or `.catch`.

Any ideas?

```
const sendRequest = req => {
  return new Promise((response, reject) => {
    console.log("sendRequest url ", req.url);
    console.log("sendRequest body", req.body);

    const instance = axios.create({
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: req.headers
    });

    instance
      .post(req.url, req.body)
      .then(body => {
        console.log("body ", body);
        response(body);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.response) {
          console.log("Error data ", err.response.data);
          console.log("Error status ", err.response.status);
          console.log("Error headers ", err.response.headers);
        } else if (err.request) {
          console.log("http.ClientRequest ", err.request);
        } else {
          console.log("Error ", err.message);
        }
        console.log("Error ", err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

I've tried several things, including duplicating the function - same problem. I've tried using axios and creating a new instance.